# How to get average from last 3 values?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I am trying to calculate an average for a golf score. I want the average to be of the persons 3 previous scores. So I am looking for a formula that will average the last 3 numbers in the column. I am open to any and all ideas. Attached is a screenshot of what I currently have.

[image: screen shot of sample data]

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(SORT(B2:B17; ROW(B2:B17)*ISNUMBER(B2:B17); 0);
 "select * limit 3"))
```

this is basically based on a false calculation where **`ROW`** number gets multiplied by the number (**`ISNUMBER`**) in the cell to find out where is the last number in a given range **`B2:B17`**. an output is then mirrored with **`SORT`** so last value becomes first from the top and then **`QUERY`** takes it all and outputs only **`3`** rows/values that are passed into **`AVERAGE`**

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the average from:**

- **player 1** numbers: **`33, 22, 11`**
- **player 2** numbers: **`30, 20, 10`**
- **player 3** numbers: **`9, 19, 29`**

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B2;
 MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(B2:B17)*--(B2:B17<>"")))-4; ; 3))
```

again based on a false calculation where **`ROW`** number gets multiplied by the cell that isn't empty **`B2:b17<>""`** in order to find out where is the last entry in a given range **`B2:B17`**. then **`ARRAYFORMULA`** generates list of values which are filtered by **`MAX`** to catch all errors (like **`13 * x`**) and then reverse **`OFFSET`** is used from a starting point/cell **B2** where is the beginning of the list, which is then restricted by last 3 values with **`-4, , 3`** and passed into **`AVERAGE`** formula.

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the average from:**

- **player 1** numbers: **`33, 22, 11`**
- **player 2** numbers: **`30,  x, 20`**
- **player 3** numbers: **`9, 19, empty cell`**

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B2:B17; MATCH(9999; B2:B17)-2):
         INDEX(B2:B17; MATCH(9999; B2:B17)))
```

this solution is based on a search for fake number **`9999`** in the range **`B2:B17`** and unless that specific number is not provided, there is no **`MATCH`** so 2 **`INDEX`** lists are generated while one of them is slightly offset by two rows **`-2`** which kind off negates all the values leaving only last 3 cells to be calculated by **`AVERAGE`** formula.

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the average from:**

- **player 1** numbers: **`33, 22, 11`**
- **player 2** numbers: **`30,  x, 20`**
- **player 3** numbers: **`9, 19, empty cell`**